# Why does Parsec not use Control.Applicative operators

Tags: haskell, parsec, alternative-functor

Using `Control.Applicative` is very useful with Parsec, but you need to always hide `<|>` and similar objects as they conflict with Parsec's own:

```
import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>), many, optional)
import Text.Parsec.Combinator
import Text.Parsec
```

Alternatively, as Antal S-Z points out, you can hide the Parsec version. However, as far as I can tell, this seems like an unnecessary restriction.

Why did parsec not simply implement these operators from Applicative?

Comment: Note that you can hide the operators from Parsec instead, and thus use only the nice general ones in your code.

Comment: Tx. I added this note to the main text

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's for historic reasons. The Parsec library predates the discovery of applicative functors and so it wasn't designed with them in mind. And I guess no one has taken the time to update Parsec to use `Control.Applicative`. There is no deep fundamental reason for not doing it.

Comment: I think there's also a problem with fixities, Parsec's `<|>` has `infixr 1` for example, while Alternative's has `infixl 4`.